# Getting parse error in php

Tags: php, wampserver, php-parse-error

For some reasons I am getting parse error on the last line of the file even it is blank. I've used connect.php file as a connection file for putting the comment into the database. I'm using wampserver as a local server & coded all by myself

Comment: Can you please post your file here?

Comment: Could be an issue with a file you include into yours if you are _really_ certain that your files syntax is clean.

Comment: you are getting down-votes because you haven't share code and actual error.

Comment: First of all, you should use IDE (especially if you are new to programming), as it helps in common errors detection. Eclipse, NetBeans, PHPStorm, you name it :). There are several alternatives, both paid and unpaid. As a quick solution, I have found a page http://phpcodechecker.com/, where you can paste your code and it should check it for common errors. I don't know, if this will work for you, but you can always try.

Answer (score -2):

It must be some thing did not closed properly , like { or some line ending left post your php file for give proper solution